# Angular-Translations: display translation for dynamically found translation key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

My angular controller may generate the messages, that I intent to translate using angular-translations.

In controller I currently assign a variable to **translation key**, such as:

```
    $scope.info = "core.projectconfig.created";
```

where that key has its translation specified as

```
 core.projectconfig.created <=> 'Project {{projectName}} created successfully'
```

As you can see, I also need to substutute projectName in translation.

I tried something like this in my view

```
 <P translate="{{info}}", translate-values="{projectName : projectData.ProjectName}"></p>
```

but it does not work. How I can translate dynamically-found translation key and also add a scope variable into the translated line?

Comment: Is `projectData` defined on your scope? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @PascalPrecht, glad to have author here. :) Could you please confirm that my syntax is correct and should work? Then it means that other part of translation, that someone else coded, is not used as it should.

Comment: Yes syntax looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject **$translate** directive which is provided by https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate in your controller.

Later use $translate like this for dynamic key:

```
$translate(translation_key)
```

Scope variables in your message can be used like below:

```
$translate(translation_key, { scope_variable_key: $scope_value })
```

e.g:`$translate("core.projectconfig.created", { projectName: $scope.projectData. ProjectName })`

Comment: Hello Monika, please help me my below ionic slide label will not translating when i switch the language but it will work fine when i closing and again opening application it will translated but not at a time                                                               <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="{{'hpgT3' | translate }}" >